# how to delete images from folder and from table also, if clicks on confirm on javascript box in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am making CRUD operation in laravel 5.4. I am deleteing an image from database and storage. I did it, but it deletes image name from database only. And do not delete from storage folder.

And I am doing one more thing, If I click on delete button then one confirmation box should be display. If click yes, then delete otherwise not delete. BUt it is also not working.

**My web.php is:**

```
Route::resource('todo','todocontroller');
```

**My todocontroller.php is:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\todo;

class todocontroller extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    $todos = todo::paginate('3');
    return view('todo.home',compact('todos'));
}

public function destroy($id)
{
    $todos = todo::find($id);

    if(\File::exists(public_path('public/storage/images/'.$todos->image))){
    \File::delete(public_path('public/storage/images/'.$todos->image));
    }

    $todos->delete();
    session()->flash('message','Deleted Successful');
    return redirect('todo');
}
}
```

**My home.blade.php is:**

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('body')
<br>
@if(session()->has('message'))
{{session()->get('message')}}
@endif

 <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"><a href="todo/create" class="btn btn-info">Add new</a>
    <h1>Todo Lists</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($todos as $todo)
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
<span><img src="{{asset('public/storage/images/'.$todo->image)}}" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;"></span>

<a href="{{'todo/'.$todo->id}}">{{$todo->title}}</a>
{{$todo->body}}

<span>
  <form class="delete" action="{{'todo/'.$todo->id}}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{method_field('DELETE')}}
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
  </form>
 </span>
</li>
@endforeach

{{$todos->links()}}
</ul>

</div>
<script>
$(".delete").on("submit", function(){
    return confirm("Do you want to delete this item?");
});
</script>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you given wrong path to the images directory. that's why delete image is not working.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $todos = todo::find($id);

    if(\File::exists(public_path('storage/images/'.$todos->image))){
    \File::delete(public_path('storage/images/'.$todos->image));
    }

    $todos->delete();
    session()->flash('message','Deleted Successful');
    return redirect('todo');
}
```

I think this will work.

Edited `home.blade.php` file

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('body')
<br>
@if(session()->has('message'))
    {{session()->get('message')}}
@endif

 <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"><a href="todo/create" class="btn btn-info">Add new</a>
    <h1>Todo Lists</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($todos as $todo)
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <span>
                    <img src="{{asset('public/storage/images/'.$todo->image)}}" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;">
                </span>
                <a href="{{'todo/'.$todo->id}}">{{$todo->title}}</a>
                {{$todo->body}}

                <span>
                    <form class="delete" action="{{'todo/'.$todo->id}}" method="POST" onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');">
                        {{csrf_field()}}
                        {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                        <button type="submit">Delete</button>
                    </form>
                </span>
            </li>
        @endforeach
        {{$todos->links()}}
    </ul>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. But I didn't understand why not add public in path. Because in img tag I have to write <img src="{{asset('public/storage/images/'.$todo->image)}}">

Comment: And my second question is: when I click on delete it should be confirmation javascript delete  or not. I I click on delete then it should be delete. But script is also not working

Comment: @cloudsoft  `public_path()` provide us full file path. but `asset()` provide us file url.

Comment: No error. It deleted successfully. But I need a confirmation box of jquery (which is write in home.blade.php). Jquery is not working.

Comment: (1/1) TokenMismatchException
in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68

Comment: use this `{!! csrf_field() !!}` instead of `{{csrf_field()}}`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [unlink](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp) function to delete file.

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $todos = todo::find($id);

    if(\File::exists(public_path('storage/images/'.$todos->image))){
        unlink(public_path('storage/images/'.$todos->image));
    }

    $todos->delete();
    session()->flash('message','Deleted Successful');
    return redirect('todo');
}
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But Error, (1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method unlink does not exist.

in Macroable.php line 74

Comment: And my second question is: when I click on delete it should be confirmation javascript delete or not. I I click on delete then it should be delete. But script is also not working